# How change field that is Entity in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have two Entities - TypeReport and GroupParameter. GroupParameter has a field TypeReport.

My Entities:

GroupParameter

```
@Entity
@Data
public class GroupParameter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = ID_GENERATOR)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private boolean common;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE_REPORT_ID", nullable = false)
    private TypeReport typeReport;

}
```

TypeReport

```
@Data
@Entity
public class TypeReport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = ID_GENERATOR)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Standard standard;

}
```

The client sends me GroupParameterDTO:

```
@Data
public class GroupParameterDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private boolean common;
    private String typeReportId;

}
```

The client can change some fields from GroupParameter and he can send any sets of fields:
- title
- title, typeReportId
- typeReportId

For example:

```
{
 title: "new Title"
}
```

Then I have:

```
GroupParameterDTO {

    private Long id = null;
    private String title = "new Title";
    private boolean common = false; //It will be ignored
    private String typeReportId = null;

}
```

When I try to change typeReport I can have two situations:

- typeReportId = null - I shouldn't change typeReport in GroupParameter
- typeReportId = something - I should change typeReport in GroupParameter without changing fileds of typeReport

What do I?

1. I find GroupParameter in DB by id:

`GroupParameter groupParametersFromDB = findById(id);`

2. I fill GroupParameter by data that I get from the client:

`groupParameterMapper.fillGroupParameters(groupParameters, groupParametersFromDB);`

```
 @Override
    public void fillGroupParameters(GroupParameter source, GroupParameter target) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( source.getTypeReport() != null ) {
            if ( target.getTypeReport() == null ) {
                target.setTypeReport( new TypeReport() );
            }
            typeReportToTypeReport( source.getTypeReport(), target.getTypeReport() );
        }
        if ( source.getTitle() != null ) {
            target.setTitle( source.getTitle() );
        }
    }

protected void typeReportToTypeReport(TypeReport typeReport, TypeReport mappingTarget) {
        if ( typeReport == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( typeReport.getId() != null ) {
            mappingTarget.setId( typeReport.getId() );
        }
        mappingTarget.setTitle( typeReport.getTitle() );
        mappingTarget.setStandard( typeReport.getStandard() );
    }
```

3. I try to save my GroupParameter:
   `groupParameterRepository.save(groupParametersFromDB);`

But I get errors.

When I try to change id:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of ru.watchlist.domain.TypeReport was altered from 1 to 3

When I don't try to change id(when the title is changed only):

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "standard" violates not-null constraint

I think that Repository tries to save typeReport instead change a link to another one in GroupParameter while saving GroupParameter.

I don't want to do any changes in typeReport when I save GroupParameter. I want only to change a link to typeReport in GroupParameter.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If a client tells you that he/she wants the type report ID of a group parameter to be 3, that doesn't mean he/she wants to change the ID of the type report.

It means he/she wants the group parameter to have *another* type report, identified by the ID 3.

So you get that type report from the database, and you assign it to the group parameter:

```
groupParameter.setTypeReport(typeReportRepository.findById(3).orElseThrow(...))
```

Comment: Should I do a request to the database each time when I want to change typeReport in GroupParameter?

Comment: It depends. Do you want to make sure the type report 3 exists, and throw a meaningful error to the client? If so, yes, you need to go to the database. If not, then you can just assume it exists, and call getOne() instead of findById() on your repository. That won't go to the database. But it will throw (hopefully) an exception at flush time due to a violated FK constraint.